# If-Else Statement C++ Error

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with this if else statement. This is part of an bigger c++ program, but there is something wrong.

```
void owed(int classchoice)
{
  double cost;
  if (classchoice == 1)
    cost = 1750.00;
  else if  (classchoice == 2)
    cost = 1500.00;
  else (classchoice == 3);
    cost = 1000.00:

  cout << "You owe about: " << cost << endl;
  cout << "Enjoy your flight!\n\n\n";
}
```

The output is ALWAYS 1000 dollars. I know for a fact that my input is correct, I have no idea what is wrong. Also I get an error at this point  "else (classchoice == 3)***;***", it tells me to to put a semicolon after this statement, I do not know why. All the help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `else (classchoice == 3);` Note the semicolon at the end (and the condition). The semicolon should not be there, and it probably should be `else if /*blah*/` or just `else`. `cost = 1000.00:` Note the colon at the end. I assume this should be a semicolon.

Comment: It doesn't need boolean expression after `else`, the syntax is `if(boolean_expression) {} else if (boolean_expression) {} else {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this

```
   void owed(int classchoice)
    {
      double cost;
      if (classchoice == 1)
        cost = 1750.00;
      else if  (classchoice == 2)
        cost = 1500.00;
      else if (classchoice == 3)
        cost = 1000.00;

      cout << "You owe about: " << cost << endl;
      cout << "Enjoy your flight!\n\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: I know that's why I've changed it. Sorry my bad.